# How add two entered number in hour format or seconds

Tags: python, class, addition, hour, seconds

Hi I want to add two elements in the class in Python with magic method '**add**'  and 'radd' ,that they show the time, the elements can be entered in two different formats: in seconds or in the hour format'16: 03: 43 '
Someone can guide me how can i add seconds with format hour:
(65480 seconds + 16:03:43 hour)

```
    class UserTime:
def __init__(self,uTime):
    self.time=uTime
    self.backup=0


def __add__(self, other):
   return self.time + other.time


'''def conv_ToHours(self,seconds):
    seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600)
    hour = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, minutes, seconds)'''
def conve_ToSeconds(self):
    """Get seconds from time."""
    h, m, s = self.time.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)

def __add__(self, other):
    global x
    x=int(self.conve_ToSeconds())+int(other.conve_ToSeconds())
    return x
def conv_ToHours(self):
    if x> 0 :
        seconds = x
        seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600)
        hour = seconds // 3600
        seconds %= 3600
        minutes = seconds // 60
        seconds %= 60
        return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, minutes, seconds)
    else:
        print('Wrong Wrong')


x= int(input('enter time:'))
y = int(input('enter time: '))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Date arithmetic is tricky and there is no reason to write your own solution. Look at the `datetime` module in the standard library. It will do correctly everything you are attempting.